# Class def not found: org/glassfish/hk2/ComponentException

Tags: java, maven, testing, jersey, hk2

I need to write junit tests for Jersey application. Now I want to test dependency injection and the problem is I created class like this:

```
@RunWith(Hk2Runner.class)
public class BinderTest {
    @Inject
    private SomeClass someClass;

    @Test
    public void passingTest() {
        someClass.getSomething("asd", "asd", "asd");
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

When run, the output is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/hk2/ComponentException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
```

I am trying to find dependency having that class to add to the pom.xml file but found nothing..
Do you guys know which maven dependency contains mentioned ComponentException class?

Dependency added in order to have Hk2Runner class:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
    <artifactId>auto-depends</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the old `auto-depends` dependency, you should also add the [`hk2-deprecated`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-deprecated/2.0.5) dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
    <artifactId>hk2-deprecated</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Another solution would be to replace the `auto-depends` dependency with the new [`hk2-testing`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-testing/2.3.0) and extend from `org.jvnet.hk2.testing.junit.HK2Runner` class.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
    <artifactId>hk2-testing</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

```
public class BinderTest extends HK2Runner { }
```

Comment: yes now the problem with dependencies is solved :) I left only hk2-junitrunner dependency. However the problem now is:   org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=CodeProvider,parent=BinderTest,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,1047503754)
How can I inject classes into this test class?

Comment: @azalut Hmm, I don't remember if `before` is automatically called. You should try to override `before` and call [`initialize`](https://hk2.java.net/hk2-junitrunner/apidocs/org/jvnet/hk2/testing/junit/HK2Runner.html#initialize%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.List,%20java.util.List%29) so that your `@Service` classes are searched (refer to the Javadoc).